# Prevent jquery toggleClass from executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

The big button, when clicked, toggles red background on each click.
Is there a way to prevent that function from executing, e.g when a button is clicked, or when a condition is performed?

```js
var counter = 0;

$(".btn").on('click', function (e) {
counter++;   
e.preventdefault;
 $(".btn").toggleClass('bgRed');
}).on('animationend', function(e) {
    $(".btn").toggleClass('bgRed');
});


$(".btn2").on('click', function (e) {
// stop toggle on .btn
});
```

```css
.bgRed{background:red}
.btn{width:340px;height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">click to Toggle </button>

<button class="btn2">Stop Toggle </button>
<button class="btn3">Continue Toggle </button>
```

Comment: e.stopPropagation()

Comment: Easiest way would be to add a conditional around the toggle, and when you click the second button, make that conditional false.

Comment: or if you mean if the function itself just add an if

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var counter = 0;

$(".btn").on('click', function(e) {
  counter++;
  e.preventDefault();

  if (!$(this).hasClass('toggleOff')) {
    $(".btn").toggleClass('bgRed');
  }
}).on('animationend', function(e) {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('toggleOff')) {
    $(".btn").toggleClass('bgRed');
  }
});


$(".btn2").on('click', function(e) {
  $('.btn').toggleClass('toggleOff');
});
```

```css
.bgRed {
  background: red
}

.btn {
  width: 340px;
  height: 100px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">click to Toggle </button>

<button class="btn2">Stop Toggle </button>
```

Comment: can you add a continue toggle please?

Comment: @GragasIncoming clicking the Stop Toggle button toggles the logic.  So if you click it once, it stops the toggle.  Clicking it again, will undo this stop logic.

Comment: brilliant i did not think about that but very smart way thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can just unbind the event from the button like this:

```
var counter = 0;

function setBtnToggle() {
    $(".btn").on('click', function (e) {
       counter++;   
       e.preventdefault;
       $(".btn").toggleClass('bgRed');
    }).on('animationend', function(e) {
        $(".btn").toggleClass('bgRed');
    });
}

$(".btn2").on('click', function (e) {
    $(".btn").off('click').off('animationend');  
});

$(".btn3").on('click', function (e) {
    setBtnToggle();
});

//set this up for page load.
setBtnToggle();
```

Comment: @GragasIncoming are you wanting to change the functionality of the button? meaning having the back ground stay red when you cllick the button and then not be red the next time you click the button. Then when you change the functionality it willl toggle on and off the redbackground in just one button click?

Comment: i want to remove button from toggling class

Answer (score 0):

Add a toggle to the outer scope that is checked before switching the color. Have the other button switch the toggle on/off, and you're set.

```js
var counter = 0;

//toggle this to enable/disable the background color switching.
let enabledBackgroundChange = true;

$(".btn").on('click', function (e) {
    counter++;   
    e.preventdefault;
    if(enabledBackgroundChange){
        $(".btn").toggleClass('bgRed');
    }
});


$(".btn2").on('click', function (e) {
    // stop toggle on .btn
    enabledBackgroundChange = !enabledBackgroundChange;
});
```

```css
.bgRed{background:red}
.btn{width:340px;height:100px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="btn">click to Toggle </button>

<button class="btn2">Stop Toggle </button>
```